# Wrap text from <span> that resides in <p>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-3">
   <p style="font-size:12pt;color:#535679;line-height:0%;">Some really cool text, <span style="font-size:12pt;color:#535679;line-height:0%;">and even more cool text</span>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, on small screens "and even more cool text" wraps on the same line resulting in "some really cool text" and "and even more cool text" overlapping.

Adding "word-wrap" or "white-space" doesn't seem to help, in this implementation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show your css as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `line-height: 0%` from both the div and span: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7352Lp01/1/)

A `line-height` of zero basically says the text is `0px` tall, so when it wraps, it wraps to the same line.

Comment: Bingo. Makes perfect sense. Thanks for the quick reply.